# Problems in IDLE: can't install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-idle

I install some libraries like numpy from my terminal but it doesn't seem to install on my IDLE which says "no module called numpy". What might be the problem?

Comment: If you have 2 python version you should check maybe you installed in Python27 and you want to use Python3

Comment: You've likely installed them for an interpreter other than the one IDLE is using.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many previous questions. Please read the comments and answers to the last two tagged python-idle.  Packages are installed for particular python binaries.  IDLE has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

Your idle IDE might have a different version of python set up as the default interpreter.
Possible solutions include:

1) Make sure that the interpreter idle starts with is the same as the one you installed numpy for

2) Make sure you get the right version for python (2 vs 3)

3) Make sure IDLE is not running from a virtualenv or you did not install numpy for a activated virtualenv (less likely)

EDIT:
Unless you edit the answer and provide additional info, a tailored solution for your question in unlikely to be found